# Bi-directional text in Unity TextMesh Pro

Tags: unity-game-engine, text, bidirectional

I have recently discovered the TextMesh Pro in unity and it is amazing but I have 1 issue.

When I write rtl (right to left) text with English text (ltr) the English word gets flip with all the text.

What should I do? Is there a setting that I need to change?

Thanks in advance

Example: as שלום

would be: sa שלום

Answer (score 1):

## You need this character: ‮

*(There's a character there, trust me)* ‮don't trust me? ;) ‭ Try highlighting this line.

It's called the [right to left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark).

XKCD [had a strip about it](https://xkcd.com/1137/):

[image: XKCD 1137]

There's also the corresponding Left to Right mark to flip things back again.  Actually getting either one in a place where you can copy it is hard, I've had the RTL one sitting in a draft email for years at this point (pretty much ever since that comic), though if I try to send the email, it gets stripped out. Similarly, I've failed four times now to capture the LTR mark to include in this post.

## Got it: ‭

HTML `&#8238;` and `&#8237;`, extracted from the HTML of this very answer (the numerical values given on wikipedia and two other sites were wrong, or at least, not giving the desired result).

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried the following:
textCom.text="שלום \u202E as"
but got the same result, and a weird sign instead of override RTL.
Can you provide working code snippet please?

Comment: @user9977758 Hmm, looks like you're right. I figured TextMeshPro was smart enough to support the character (it supports so much else!). I can't get bidirectional text to work anywhere in Unity (not with regular UI text and not with MeshText). I *did* find [this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/localization/easy-alphabet-arabic-56625) which purports to support mixed text (spcifically Arabic, Hebrew *should* work IMO), but it is $20.