# Bidirectional text in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, text-processing

I have been using Unity3D for about 2 years now, and one thing that I can't figure out is how to have bidirectional text.

In my programs I write in Hebrew and English. The problem is that Textmesh Pro doesn't support it at all. It flips the Hebrew words, and if I enable RTL option, it flips **English and numbers**.

So far, I tried to flip the English words and the numbers before I show it in the text box, but it doesn't work properly. I detect English words by the first character of every word.

I would post the code, when I would be next to my computer.

Is there anything I can do to fix it¿ Maybe some code to flip the problematic words somehow.

Comment: Have you tried the LTR/RTL character? https://xkcd.com/1137/ I don't *expect* it to work, but its worth a try.

Comment: @Draco18s Yes, it didn't work, just showed weird sign

Comment: That's what I expected, based on other similar unicode objects.

Comment: [Oh hey, we've been here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294964/bi-directional-text-in-unity-textmesh-pro). I [reported unicode combining marks not combinging](https://fogbugz.unity3d.com/default.asp?1109982_bdnahkgs9btg3dpn) in February, so I don't think anything's changed in the last year.

Comment: @Draco18s Wow I forgot about it, does it help to report?

Comment: Is not there any code I can use to flip the words¿

Comment: Reporting at least makes Unity aware of the problem. As for code to flip the words, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, [this asset](http://github.com/mnarimani/RTLTMPro) does the trick better then what I achieved.
Need some modifications but still solves the problem really good.